# SQL Server 2008 Chaining Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

Is there a way to have multiple "tiers" for a merge replication in SQL Server 2008.  For example I have SiteA with SQL Server 2008 that has a publication setup on TestDB.  SiteB, also with SQL Server 2008 is subscribed to the SiteA publication for TestDB. SiteB then has a publication on its TestDB and multiple instances of SQL Server Express 2008 subscribe to the publication for TestDB on SiteB.

The goal here being the local SQL Express instances are merge replicating with site B and then site B is merge replicating with Site A.

I tried setting this up, but when I got to SiteB to setup the publication I got the following message

"You cannot create a merge publication in this database because it contains one or more anonymous or local merge subscriptions. To create a merge publication, drop the existing anonymous or local merge subscriptions, create the publication, and then recreate the subscriptions."

Answer (score 1):

It appear this works, but the first tier of replication (the republisher) needs to be a server side push subscription instead of a pull subscriptions.